# View models of type ".xml" or ".dot" files within Java JFrame

Tags: java, xml, swing, graphviz

I wanted to know how to produce a JFrame that would visually show a model that is formatted in ".xml" or ".dot" format.

I know .dot format is generally used by Graphviz to view the graphs created but is there a way to use Graphviz within Java to view the models in a JFrame

So far I can create the models in .xml and .dot format and view them using Graphviz software.

My concern is just visually producing the .xml and .dot files within a java program preferably within a JFrame.

Comment: XML is easy to 'display'.  Whether the rendering is to your expectation is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to try a new library, please check http://jgraphviz.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

For some university project I once had working code to render a dot file to graphviz. The key ingredients were matching the fonts used and parsing the textual output of dot to generate Java drawing instructions based on that. So for the fully layed out output of dot this works well enough.

For XML, you'll have to be more specific about the kind of XML you have in mind, and the kind of rendering you expect. A simple document tree should be rather easy.